GeneratedKeyHolder not returning generated id for Column created using UUID() in MySQL table
My table def in MySQL looks like this :
create table if not exists CUSTOMER (
                                        CUSTOMER_ID CHAR(36) DEFAULT (UUID()) primary key,
                                        MOBILE VARCHAR(10) ,
                                        NAME VARCHAR(45),
                                        EMAIL VARCHAR(100),
                                        GENDER VARCHAR(1)
                                        );

When I try to insert and fetch the inserted id using JdbcTemplate & PreparedStatementCreator using these lines of code :
GeneratedKeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        int rowsAffected = jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER1 (MOBILE) VALUES (?)",Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                statement.setString(1, mobileNumber);
                return statement;
            }
        }, holder);
        return holder.getKey().toString();

holder.getKey() returns null.
Am i doing anything wrong ?
I am using Spring boot 3.3.4,
MySQL 8.0.40
I tried changing my jdbcUrl to this :
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
But this also does not worked for me.
I want to fetch the last inserted CUSTOMER_ID right after insertion of my record.

I would double check what exactly spring boot includes in Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS. Mysql API has designated function to return value of auto increment after an insert, but there is no such functionality for UUIDs. Mysql also does not support the returning clause for data modification statements. For UUIDs the only way to get the last inserted value is to do a select based on date or  auto increment column
